# How to upload a large file with more than 500 mb to a ftp server using asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, ftp

I changed the web config also from 4 mb to : 2,147,483,647 bytes

On the dev server it works fine and uploads up to 800 mb without an issue. But on the stage server, it doesn't support even 400 mb file,  I get the error: Bad gateway or Gateway timeout error

Is the issue from IIS Server in stage?

Is there any other solution is there for this issue
because the dev environment the c# the code works fine but same source code(c#) on the stage server does  not work.

Comment: Bad gateway would seem to indicate a router or firewall issue. When uploading a large file, you have to keep the http session open for a long time. Also, is there enough free disk space?

Comment: If you're going to do this from an ASP.NET application, you'll want to use some established background method such as [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/), [Quartz.NET](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), or [QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/05/07/scheduling-background-jobs-from-an-asp-net-application-in-net-4-5-2). How are you doing it now?